# Letterpress doesn't work with UIColor from a pattern image

Tags: ios, ios7, nsattributedstring, letterpress

I would like to use a an image as the color of an letter-pressed label but something is not working right and I am not sure what.
I create the color with

```
UIImage *redImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red"];
UIColor *redColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledRedImage];
```

When I create the attributes

`NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : redColor, NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle};`
the label is letter-pressed but the color is white.

When using `NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : redColor};`, the color is set correctly so I know that the color is created correctly.

`NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor], NSTextEffectAttributeName : NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle};` works perfectly.

So to sum up:

1. Letterpress + custom color = white letterpressed text
2. Letterpress + system color = correctly colored and letterpressed text
3. Custom color + no letterpress = correctly colored

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm a similar issue.